# e.which ENTER key enabled only if input field focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a e.which of jquery for running a function on press of ENTER, but I want this function to be called only if the particular input field is focused (where the cursor is blinking).

My current jquery function.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var page = $("#userpage").val();

        if(page > 0) {
            $("#search").click();
        } else {
            $('.save').click();
        }
    }
});
```

I want that **$("#search").click();** to be called only if the **#search_text** is focused or has some input, because I have few more input fields and users tend to press enter, and on Enter this function is called.

Thank You.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would attach the event listener to that specific input element:

```
$('#search_text').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        // do it
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree but would suggest using the `keypress` event rather than the `keyup` event, since it will fire sooner and also has reliable character codes for printable characters in all mainstream browsers.

Answer (score 1):

just add this line to your function inside your second **if** statement:

```
$('#search_text').focus(function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event for the #search_text element, instead of the whole document. That way it'll only be triggered when the element has the focus.

Answer (score 0):

when we apply the bind to `$(document)`, the bind occurs when the document has `focus`. We can use the same thing here. By using `$(#search-text)` in the keybind, we make it so that the keybind is only triggered when `#search-text` is focused.

```
$(#search-text).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var page = $("#userpage").val();

        if(page > 0) {
            $("#search").click();
        } else {
            $('.save').click();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You also need to add: `e.preventDefault()`;

```
$('document').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == '13') {
     e.preventDefault();
     var page = $("#userpage").val();
   }
});
```

Comment: Calling jQuery giving the string `'document'` doesn't attach the event to the document element. You need to use `$(document)` instead, without the quotes. Also, when you call `preventDefault()` all subsequent "default" events will not be triggered anymore.